# What does " Cannot read tablet : Incompatible types" mean?

Tags: google-bigquery

We ran this query on Bigquery:

```
SELECT DateTime, Source, MachineName, LogLevel, Identifier, Message, Exception 
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(XXXX.EventLog_, TIMESTAMP(Current_Date()), TIMESTAMP(Current_Date()))
Where source like 'Sync' and (MachineName like 'WEBNEW' or Identifier like 'WEBNEW')
Order by DateTime desc
LIMIT 100;
```

It gave us :
Error: Cannot read tablet : Incompatible types. 'DateTime' : TYPE_MESSAGE 'DateTime' : TYPE_INT64
*Job ID: red-road-574:job_t5gM9MysBFi20PFZ88kgTO8ygvQ*

When we only got rid of " Order by DateTime desc", the query ran well.

We wonder why, and how to fix it.

Comment: well, tried after ten minutes, the problem's gone for whatever no reasons....

Answer (score 2):

Transient issue in BigQuery - everything should be working normal now.

Comment: Thanks. Could you shed more light on the "transient issue? "

Comment: I have the same issue, but it doesn't seem to be transient. It keeps occurring for couple of days now. Removing the table and trying again is the only thing that solves it. see job_PDE_IPLhYQG1PkoYdEodCoRzs5Q

Comment: If anyone else runs into this, the workaround is to:
1. Run your select into query with "limit 0" so it will create the schema 
2. Remove the limit and run the query normally

Comment: That was a bug, but we finally hunted it down and fixed for good. You should never see this error again.